# Virus changed Google Chrome installation folder

Tags: malware, virus, chrome, windows-10

I got the malware zooarm on my system, and it has changed my Google Chrome folder path to this:

> **Executable Path:** C:\Program Files (x86)\Zooarm\Application\chrome.exe
>
> **Profile Path:** C:\Users\Shaharyar\AppData\Local\Zooarm\User Data\Default

What problems or security issues can it cause me?

I am using Windows 10. It also stopped my Windows Defender, and I don't know how it got so many privileges to do such things.

Comment: Security.SE is not really an anti-virus support site. You might receive more help from Superuser.

Answer (score 0):

If there's been a malware intrusion, chances are that they have elevated their privilege to administrator. If so, then you should probably think about reinstalling Windows rather than removing the malware, as its hard and toilsome to measure the impact of the malware on your OS.